# How to auto apply the file path from a cell in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Now I am using this code for running a Excel Chart Template on bar charts:

```
Apply Saved Chart Template
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\Bosco\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\Bar Chart.crtx" _
        )
```

Since this link will be decided dynamically, if I save `C:\Users\Bosco\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\Bar Chart.crtx` into cell A1, how can I auto apply the path of A1 in VBA so that once I change the path in A1, the VBA will automatically follow? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set value of cell A1 to argument, then using this parameter for code

```
Dim sPath As String
sPath = Cells(1, 1).Value
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate (sPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Apply Saved Chart Template
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate (Worksheets("Name").Range("A1"))
```

Something like this should work, I suppose.